# c# socket cannot receive multicast messages

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, network-programming, udp

I have a C# script that sends a query to a multicast address and listens on a port to receive the replies. When I try this script on my private laptop it works, but when I try it on my work laptop it fails.

The script is used to find devices on my network. The manufacturer of the devices has a program for finding these devices. The program can receive the messages on my work laptop but my script can't. I don't know why my script cant receive these messages.

I already checked the IP rules and I can see that there is a rule for the specific port and I even added the rule just to be sure.

I can also see the devices responding to my query in Wireshark.

```
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("224.0.0.251");

Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(ip, IPAddress.Any));// Add socket to the multicast group

IPEndPoint listener = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(localIP), 5353);

IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
EndPoint senderRemote = (EndPoint)sender;

socket.Bind(listener);
Console.WriteLine("server started listening\n");


// Receive messages
while (_running)
{

    byte[] data = new byte[3024];
    socket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref senderRemote);
    string str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
    // Console.WriteLine(str);

    cameraIP = senderRemote.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(cameraIP);
    // Console.WriteLine(senderRemote.ToString());
}
```

This is the Wireshark:
My ip is 192.168.0.2, and the device is 192.168.0.3 using mdns.

[wireshark picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5KWs.png)

I also have the file wireshark makes: https://github.com/hamza-outa/links-n-such/blob/main/wireshark.pcapng

Comment: When you say it fails, does it throw an error you can share? Also, can you send us wireshark or tcpdump captures of both the sender and an ip who is supposed to be receiving?

Comment: no the script runs but i just receive nothing, i don't get an error

Comment: Are you sure the multicast receiver is actually receiving? You can check using a program like wireshark, on both ends.

Comment: Also, you should upload the code for the client that is supposed to be listening and responding to this multicast.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b the thing is the client is a camera, and i dont have the code that the camera uses to reply.

Comment: So in wireshark, you see responses, but not in your program? Or are you only receiving from some sources? It is probably because you are listening for packets on a different port than you are sending. What port are the incoming packets going to?

Comment: yes in wireshark i can see them responding. and the destination port is 5353

Comment: It may be a firewall issue? Windows firewall tries to be smart. It sees you send a message from one port the the camera, then it sees the camera respond to a different port, it assumes they are unrelated and blocks it. I assume other OSs would be similar.Try disabling the firewall on whatever OS you have.